# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am getting "Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference" in IE11.  The function looks like this:

```
function chgSupr(val) {
    var suprDD = eval('document.getElementById.col1LIAB_SUPERVISOR_CODE');
    suprDD.length = 0;
    if (!(val == '_')) {
        var suprAryStr = '<select name="col1LIAB_SUPERVISOR_CODE" style="width: 150px;" required>';
        var suprDD = eval('document.getElementById.col1LIAB_SUPERVISOR_CODE');
        suprDD.length = 0;
        suprAryStr += '<option value=""""></option>';
        for (i = 0; i < suprAry[val].length; i++) {
            tmpAry = suprAry[val][i].split('|~|');
            suprDD.length++;
            if (tmpAry[0].length > 1) {
                suprDD[i].value = tmpAry[0];
                suprDD[i].text = tmpAry[1] + '|' + tmpAry[0];
            } else {
                suprDD[i].value = "";
                suprDD[i].text = "";
            }
            suprAryStr += '<option value="' + tmpAry[0] + '">' + tmpAry[1] + '</option>';
        }
        suprAryStr += '</select>';

    } else {
        suprDD.length = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing it to error out.

Comment: Without a working example, and with a number of uses of the 'length' property, we can't know exactly which is the culprit (could be multiple in the end). Those eval statements are definitely suspect though since getElementById is a function and any property accessed from that will evaluate to undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var suprDD = eval('document.getElementById.col1LIAB_SUPERVISOR_CODE') // is not corrent.
document.getElementById("") //use this or 
eval('document.getElementById("")').
```

eval should be avoided.